# pyramid_beaker sometimes suffers SqlAlchemy error: already defined for this MetaData instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, beaker

I'm using beaker for my session cache in Pyramid web app, since my production environment will have multiple web servers. During development, under circumstances that cause beaker to re-initialize I get an error that beaker_cache table is already added to the meta. I'm worried that this will occur in production and I don't quite know what causes it. Has anyone else reported this problem?

Error:

```
Table 'beaker_cache' is already defined for this MetaData instance
```

I've dug into source code and see where it's happening.  I've tried to specify a beaker_cache table in my ini.  Here's my ini for beaker:

```
session.type = ext:database
session.lock_dir = ./beaker_lock
session.url = xxxx
session.auto = True
# tried to add extend existing hoping it would find it's way to the sa configuration
session.extend_existing=True
session.key = xxxx
session.secret = xxxx
session.table_name = beaker_cache
```